# Active component cant create obj error

Tags: vbscript, ftp, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to script for file transferring ,its works fine when am clicking manually the script.But when am trying to run as Scheduling task i receiving an error  "Active component cant create obj",i don't know what went wrong in my script? 
For your reference i have my script below.

```
Dim Mysite 
Set MySite = CreateObject("CuteFTPPro.TEConnection") 
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
MySite.Protocol = "FTP"
MySite.Host = "www.domainname.com"
MySite.Login = "xxxxx"
MySite.Password = "xxx"
MySite.UseProxy = "BOTH"
MySite.Connect
MySite.UploadAsync "C:\sampletest\abc.flv" 
MySite.RemoteFolder = "/test/abc.flv" 
MySite.Disconnect
MySite.Close
```

FYI my machine is windows 2008 64 bit system

Comment: Just taking a stab here. You said you're on a 64-bit system? Is the `CuteFTPPro` ActiveX control a 32-bit or 64-bit control? My guess is that you might be using the 32-bit version of `wscript.exe` (in the `SysWow64` folder) when running it manually but Task Scheduler may be using the 64-bit version of `wscript.exe` (in the `System32` folder).

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses everybody.CuteFTPPro Acivex is 64 bit control,I checked my wscript also it is running only in 64 bit system.If task scheduler runs an application in 64 bit means why i am receiving "Active component cant create obj error".
My task settings are as below
Genral:Run whether user is logged in
       Run with Highest Privileges
Trigger:Daily once
Action: 
     
        program/Script : Cutescript.bat
        Start in       :C:\CuteTest_Script\testscript\

Can you pl tell me any Suggestions? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In most cases issue raised by one of the following:

```
User does not have proper permission to run a scheduler

User does not have proper access to the folders/files listed

Application you are using running under different permission set for logged in user and system account which is used by Task Scheduler.

OS is not recognizing what application version it have to execute 32 or 64 bit when attempt to execute scheduled task.
```

Take a closer look on those situations, make adjustments and it will work.

Comment: :Thanks for your reply,Can you pl refer my comment above which i replied to bond.